# Navbar in an iframe

Tags: html, css, localhost

I'm trying to set up a local-only website with a top navbar. As the site will be multiple pages and the navbar options can change frequently, I thought I'd be able to use SSI or something similar to have all the pages reference. I asked about that here: [How to mimic SSI for a local site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410360/how-to-mimic-ssi-for-a-local-site)

It was suggested there that I use an iframe, so that's what I'm attempting now. However, when the menu drops down, it stops at the bottom of the iframe. Is there a way for the menu divs to distend out of the iframe?

Comment: No. When you say local, you mean from hard-disk/file system?

Comment: You have lots of options, one of the best/easiest would be to set up a local PHP environment and split your header/footer files up. Alternatively, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: @mplungjan Yes. It's a site on a networked drive.

Comment: @AlexanderWigmore I'm not able to set up a PHP environment. There's no real server environment set up for this.

Comment: Then i suggest you include the navbar as a js file that updates the innerHTML of a div with scrollbars like this in the link posted above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15250208/295783

Comment: I actually like the jQuery answer in the thread @AlexanderWigmore linked to. That seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Robby - that does not necessarily work in all browsers  - Chrome for example does not like to AJAX from file system

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not able to get the answer your linked to work right. I want the div to have a fixed position, but whenever I do that, the div doesn't even appear. It appears like it should if I don't add CSS to it.

Comment: We need to see code

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a `<div class="nav"></div>`
2. Add `<script src="nav.js"></script>`
3. use something like this:

---

```js
var navDiv = document.getElementById("nav");
if (navDiv) {
  var active = "/page3"; // location.pathname
  var navHtml = `
    <ul>
      <li class="${active=="/home"?"active":""}">Home</li>
      <li class="${active=="/about"?"active":""}">About</li>
      <li class="${active=="/page1"?"active":""}">Page1</li>
      <li class="${active=="/page2"?"active":""}">Page2</li>
      <li class="${active=="/page3"?"active":""}">Page3</li>
      <li class="${active=="/page4"?"active":""}">Page4</li>
      <li class="${active=="/page5"?"active":""}">Page5</li>
    </ul>`;
  navDiv.innerHTML = navHtml;
  //  document.querySelector(".active").scrollIntoView();

  var el = document.querySelector(".active")
  navDiv.scroll({
    top: el.offsetTop - 10,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}

#nav {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav"></div>
```